# Recursively looping through neighbors with an igraph object

Tags: r, igraph

Appreciate any pointers to the below output that want. I know I need to do some form of recursion but sure how to do that exactly.

I have the following code

```
>> start of code
# BOM data
library("dplyr")
library(igraph)

text1 <- ("
          matnr,comp
          FG1,SA1
          FG1,SA2
          SA1,SA3
          SA1,SA4
          SA1,SA5
          SA5,SA6
          FG2,SA1
          FG2,SA8
          SA8,SA9
          SA9,SA10
          SA9,SA11")

df1 <- read.table(textConnection(text1),  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, sep=",")
head(df1)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(df1)
net
neighbors_FG1 <- neighbors(net, v=c("FG1"), mode=c("out"))
neighbors_FG1

neighbors_FG2 <- neighbors(net, v=c("FG2"), mode=c("out"))
neighbors_FG2            

neighbors_SA1 <- neighbors(net, v=c("SA1"), mode=c("out"))
neighbors_SA1

>> end of code
```

I want to be able to produce a data frame like below. I would think that this will need some sort of recursion and I would like to get help with this. If you can even help me with how I can get to the output below, that will be great.

```
FG,level,material,Comp  
FG1,1,FG1,SA1  
FG1,1,FG1,SA2  
FG1,2,SA1,SA3  
FG1,2,SA1,SA4  
FG1,2,SA1,SA5  
FG1,3,SA5,SA6  
FG2,1,FG2,SA1  
FG2,1,FG2,SA8  
FG2,2,SA8,SA9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `igraph` option

```
lst <- lapply(
  names(V(net))[degree(net, mode = "in") == 0],
  function(x) {
    d <- Filter(
      is.finite,
      setNames(
        c(distances(net, x, mode = "out") + 1),
        names(V(net))
      )
    )
    cbind(
      FG = x,
      merge(
        setNames(get.data.frame(
          induced_subgraph(
            net,
            names(d)
          )
        ), c("matnr", "comp")),
        setNames(
          rev(stack(d)),
          c("matnr", "lvl")
        )
      )
    )
  }
)

res <- `row.names<-`(
  subset(
    do.call(rbind, lst),
    ave(seq_along(matnr), matnr, comp, lvl, FUN = seq_along) == 1
  ), NULL
)
```

which gives

```
> res
    FG matnr comp lvl
1  FG1   FG1  SA1   1
2  FG1   FG1  SA2   1
3  FG1   SA1  SA3   2
4  FG1   SA1  SA4   2
5  FG1   SA1  SA5   2
6  FG1   SA5  SA6   3
7  FG2   FG2  SA1   1
8  FG2   FG2  SA8   1
9  FG2   SA8  SA9   2
10 FG2   SA9 SA10   3
11 FG2   SA9 SA11   3
```

Comment: Thanks again Mr. ThomaslsCoding! Certainly appreciate your help and code!

Answer (score 1):

I use `tidyverse`, `igraph` and `tidygraph` to solve this question:

1. Converts the type of `net` so that it can be manipulated by the TidyGraph package

```r
gr <- as_tbl_graph(net)
```

2. Get a vector that contains the correspondence between nodes' names and their order.

```
name_vector <- gr %>%
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  as_vector()
```

3. Define the node to strat the search

```r
start_node = 1 # The first node is FG1
```

4. Generate the variables you want:

```
temp <- gr %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(
    # Get the nodes from which each node is visited in a breath first search
    material = bfs_parent(root = start_node), 
    # Get the succession in which the nodes are visited in a depth first search
    level = bfs_dist(root = start_node)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  rename(Comp = name)
```

5. Replace the order with a name

```
temp <- temp %>%
  mutate(FG = name_vector[start_node],
         material = name_vector[material])
```

And that's the result:

```r
> temp %>% arrange(level)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Comp  material level FG   
  <chr> <chr>    <int> <chr>
1 SA1   FG1          1 FG1  
2 SA2   FG1          1 FG1  
3 SA5   SA1          2 FG1  
4 SA3   SA1          2 FG1  
5 SA4   SA1          2 FG1  
6 SA6   SA5          3 FG1
```

Based on the code above, We found all the cases where `start_node = 1`.
You can use loops to redefine the `start_node` and combine these results together.

Comment: Thanks so much for going through this and your suggestions. I will try it on the larger data set that I have.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to run the code and seem to be having problems with "tidygraph". Please see below - not sure what the reason for this is:  I am pasting the error message below.    

> library("tidygraph")   
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidygraph’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidygraph’ was built under R version 3.5.3

Comment: An update to my comment earlier.  Yes. I had some problems wit the loading of the packages and Stackoverflow has many references to this same problem that others had. I took the shortest path by installing the latest version of R and RStudio and that took care of the problem. Thanks,
Satish

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `neigborhood()` we can use `igraph::ego()` to get a vector of nodes that
are reachable by from the nodes of interest. Combined with `igraph::induced_subgraph()` and `igraph::distances()` we can get all the information you
are looking for. See below how to assemble it all.
`purrr` has `map_dfr()` which works like `lapply()` but it also executes `bind_rows()` on the resulting `list`.

```r
library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'purrr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:igraph':
#> 
#>     compose, simplify
```

We now create a vector of all the nodes we want to describe the neigborhood of.

```r
FGs <- c("FG1", "FG2")
```

We feed that vector into `map_dfr()` that executes the function defined in `~{...}` on each value in `FGs`.

```r
res <- map_dfr(FGs, ~{
  
  # Inside the function we first extract the subgraph that is reachable by
  # outgoing edges from our node of interest.
  
  sub_g <- induced_subgraph(net, 
                            ego(net, 
                                order = diameter(net), 
                                nodes=.x, 
                                mode=c("out"))[[1]])
  
  # We then calculate the distances from our node of interest to
  # all other nodes, transform the distances to a data.frame/tibble and
  # join it with the edgelist of the subgraph.
  
  distances(sub_g, .x) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = "Comp") %>% 
    inner_join(as_data_frame(sub_g), by = c("Comp" = "to")) %>% # Join with edgelist
    mutate(FG = .x) %>% 
    dplyr::select(FG, level = 2, material = from, Comp)
}) %>% 
  arrange(FG, level)
```

Result:

```r
res
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    FG    level material Comp 
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 FG1       1 FG1      SA1  
#>  2 FG1       1 FG1      SA2  
#>  3 FG1       2 SA1      SA5  
#>  4 FG1       2 SA1      SA3  
#>  5 FG1       2 SA1      SA4  
#>  6 FG1       3 SA5      SA6  
#>  7 FG2       1 FG2      SA1  
#>  8 FG2       1 FG2      SA8  
#>  9 FG2       2 SA1      SA5  
#> 10 FG2       2 SA8      SA9  
#> 11 FG2       2 SA1      SA3  
#> 12 FG2       2 SA1      SA4  
#> 13 FG2       3 SA5      SA6  
#> 14 FG2       3 SA9      SA10 
#> 15 FG2       3 SA9      SA11
```

Comment: Thanks so much for going through this and your suggestions. I will try it on the larger data set that I have.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am getting the following error when I execute your suggested code. I am afraid I am not familiar with some of the constructs that you have used. Appreciate your help with this.  

This is the error that I am getting (below)  
Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 6

Comment: I saw your suggested edit. Since the `arrange(2)` seems to cause issues for you we can move it to the end of the chain. I have updated my answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to your original code. I was wondering if you could take the time and break down your code into steps and explain a bit - so that the individual steps are understood better. That will help me for sure and perhaps others.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. When I am running this with a larger dataset, I am getting some errors like so: "Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, nodes) : Invalid vertex names". I was wondering if you could help break this down into steps so that when I get a situation like this, I can skip the loop or put an IF condition for this. 
I am sure that this is because of the dataset. But I want to continue with Finished Goods that work and skip the data that is not working. It will be great if I can break this down so that I can put an IF condition. Thanks again,
Satish

Comment: What you are looking for is  called "exception handling". The purrr package has the `safely()` and `possibly()` functions to deal with this. `Base R`  exception handling is done with `try()`, `tryCatch()` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I need to start using these things - maybe get to from where I am a Padwan to an older Padwan if not a Jedi :)